# Cron job not working: importing to calcurse

Tags: cron

I'm trying to create a cron job to fetch an iCal file from Google Calendars and import it to calcurse.

Here is the script *google_sync.sh* :

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
wget https://calendar.google.com/calenddar/ical/<<my email>>/<<my key>>/basic.ics -O ~/.calcurse/dumps/google.sam.ics

calcurse -i /home/sam/.calcurse/dumps/google/sam.ics

uniq /home/sam/.calcurse/apts > /home/sam/.calcurse/temp
cat /home/sam/.calcurse/temp > /home/sam/.calcurse/apts
rm /home/sam/.calcurse/temp
```

And here is what I added with `chrontab -e`

```
*/20 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/sam/.calcurse/scripts/google_sync.sh
```

Comment: "Not working"? How do you know that? Rerun your cron job with `set -x` near the beginning of your script

Comment: does the script run fine when run from the command line (its missing the # at the begining)? does it have output?

Comment: what's `/usr/bin/sh`?

Comment: yea, try /bin/sh instead... nice spot @Sebastian Stark

Comment: wait, look at that too... the script is bash and he is running it with sh (or trying to) change cron to /bin/bash /home/sam/.calcurse/scripts/google_sync.sh

Comment: I changed /usr/bin/sh to /bin/sh, and that seems to have done the trick, thanks :D

Comment: @Sam Phillips please be sure to except answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect application link: `/usr/bin/sh` which should be `/bin/sh`